# I get this error when trying to create a new React application

Tags: reactjs

I keep getting this E404 error in my shell when trying to create a react app. I may have deleted important files from my computer like an absolute noob. A possible solution I tried was using `npm set registry https://registry.npmjs.org` but this didn't help. I've been searching for ways to resolve this issue but haven't found a solution. Has anyone encountered this? Any advice? Thanks for reading!

`npm get registry` returns
`https://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry`

```
Creating a new React app in /home/elilogbro/portfolio.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry/lodash.sortby/-/lodash.sortby-4.7.0.tgz - not_found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'lodash.sortby@https://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry/lodash.sortby/-/lodash.sortby-4.7.0.tgz' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/elilogbro/.npm/_logs/2022-11-20T20_32_00_327Z-debug-0.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting portfolio/ from /home/elilogbro
Done.
```

Comment: what version of nodejs and npm you are using

Comment: @monim npm => 9.1.2, node => 16.18.1

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command (note the config)

```
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org
```

[NPM registry docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/registry)

Comment: When you say not the config, do you mean leave out the word ‘config’ in the command? If so, I did try this and it didn’t work!

Comment: no just copy and past all of the command  `npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org`

Comment: @monim same error is showing unfortunately

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

if you have installed `create-react-app` globally . uninstall it  using

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

then run  :

```
npx create-react-app your_app
```

Comment: No luck on this one either

Comment: what command did you type to create react app

Comment: npx create-react-app portfolio

Comment: try with another internet connexion , maybe you are behind a proxy

Comment: just tried this with no luck either

Comment: try `npm cache clean --force` then `npm rebuild`  then  run `npx create-react-app portfolio`

Comment: Didn’t work lol all good ideas though

Comment: if so  then run `npm cache clean -f` then `rm -rf node_modules` then `npm i`

Comment: Hey I appreciate your help! I fixed the issue by physically navigating to the .npmjs file and changing the registry in there. Works perfectly now!